# Angularjs - What is the correct way to create `factory` and how to use them?

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angular, I would like to understand the factory method.

I tried to create a factory method to my app with different ways. but nothing works for me - why?

as well which is the correct way to create factory methods and do we have multiple ways to create factory methods ? - if so please  explain with their advantages and disadvantages ?

here is my try :

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['authService' ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

//type 1
app.factory('appFactory', function(){
  console.log(" called from app factory")
})

//type 2
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory( 'myFactory', function(){

  console.log("called from factory");

})

//type 3
angular.module("authService", [])

.factory("Auth", function( $http, $q, AuthToken ) {

  console.log(" i am called from auth factory")


})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qyIUwhhjIUuubvlz2EZ8?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [a forked version](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfcVbRODqrqQeLSzWK4W?p=preview) of your plunker

> - Your factory must return something. Check out the return statement in the plunker
> - You should inject the factory in your controller `MainCtrl` for the factory to be initialized. That's why the `console.log`s were not printed.

**Optimal usage of factory/services**

> According to the widely used [John Papa's angular 1 style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#iife) below is the optimal approach. Read more about angular guidelines on the [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('logger', logger);

function logger() { }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

With factories you can create objects. A simple example that can help you get started is this:

```
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.factory('Post', ['$http', function($http) {
    var service = {
        all: all,
        get: get
    };

    return service;

    function all() {
        return $http
            .get('api/posts/')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }

    function get(id) {
        return $http
            .get('api/posts/' + id);
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}])
.controller('PostsController', ['Post', function(Post){
    var self = this;
    self.posts = Posts.get();
}]);
```

So check i can simply inject it in my controller and then call its methods with ease. That way there is a separation of concerns and you can keep all this logic away from controllers and components. There is a great article about factories and services also [here](https://toddmotto.com/factory-versus-service)

Answer (score 0):

The best example you can get here..

http://embed.plnkr.co/LdZnjS43g6d2HXtHttG4/

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

Factory is used to create the service. Services are java script function once we define the factory we can use it any where in the application.
Example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<h3>{{hello}}</h3>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory("test",function(){
    var fact={}     //Creating Object
    fact.love=function(){   //Access love method through the fact object
        var serve="This is test for  factory";
        return serve;
    }
    return fact;          //return object
})
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, test) {
    $scope.hello=test.love(); //assign the test factory function in ctrler
});
</script>
```